# Zod: How to tell Typescript that you're taking out a specific key:value from a z.object, and appending it to a list

Tags: typescript, zod

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const FirstZobj = z.object({
    items: z.array(z.object({ hello: z.literal("world") })),
});

const OtherZObj = z.object({
    items: z.array(z.object({ goodbye: z.literal("planet") })),
});

type Possibles = typeof FirstZobj | typeof OtherZObj;

type PossibleItems =
    | z.infer<typeof FirstZobj>["items"]
    | z.infer<typeof OtherZObj>["items"];

const lookDeep = async<T extends Possibles>(obj: unknown, validator: T) => {
    const valid = validator.safeParse(obj);
    const extractedItems: PossibleItems = [];
    if (valid.success) {
        for (const item of valid.data.items) {
            extractedItems.push(item);
                              //^^^^ error is here
        }
    }
    return extractedItems;
};

const data1 = { items: [{ hello: "world" }, { hello: "world" }] };
const data2 = { items: [{ goodbye: "planet" }] };
const data3 = { items: [{ greetings: "mars" }] };

console.log(lookDeep(data1, FirstZobj));
console.log(lookDeep(data2, OtherZObj));
console.log(lookDeep(data3, FirstZobj));
```

I have all these objects with items: [{}], but in the function we're not sure which validator is being passed. My issue is that on `extractedItems.push(items)`, it gives me the following type error:

```
Argument of type '{ hello: "world"; } | { goodbye: "planet"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ hello: "world"; } & { goodbye: "planet"; }'.
  Type '{ hello: "world"; }' is not assignable to type '{ hello: "world"; } & { goodbye: "planet"; }'.
    Property 'goodbye' is missing in type '{ hello: "world"; }' but required in type '{ goodbye: "planet"; }'.ts(2345)
scratch.ts(8, 31): 'goodbye' is declared here.
```

Specifically the `Type '{ hello: "world"; }' is not assignable to type '{ hello: "world"; } & { goodbye: "planet"; }'` part. Why is it using an intersection type? I have `Possibles` and `PossibleItems` both as union types, and no where is saying that I have to figure out for both...

Except for `T extends Possibles`, I'm guessing, but I don't know how to fix that. I need to confine `validator` to a member of `Possibles` but once I'm inside, I need `PossibleItems` to take over...or something else. I'm really lost. I tried getting the chatgippity to help but this was too much for it, and just kept recommending to me that I cast it as `PossibleItems[]`.

Originally I had `const extractedItems: z.infer<T>["items"] = []` but that didn't work, so I made it a union type, and they both give the same error. What am I missing? The value within valid.data.items should be an array, and each `item` in that array is the object, and the `PossibleItems` is a list of said objects!

Comment: Use `PossibleItems[number][]` instead, as if you want to push into `A[] | B[]` you must push `A & B` as you don't know to which you push

Comment: Actually why not just `return !valid.success ? undefined : valid.data.items.slice();`

Comment: @Dimava Thank you very much! Both of these solutions work perfectly well, so I think I'm going to use the `PossibleItems[number][]` because that was more of my original intention. The .slice() might work, but I'm using this for using zod to validate a 3rd part api,, so I'm going to have multiple `items:[]` I think. It's probably better for performance, but the mental model for the .push() is easier, so I'll stick with it until I make my tRPC routes stable. I'm relatively new to Typescript, learning by using the T3 stack, so I appreciate the lesson on .slice()

Comment: If you are `shallowClone`ing the array `array.slice()` or `[...array]` is more idiomatic as it's cleanly copying the array. Older libraries had `.clone()`, but since `.slice()` does exactly that it's not in std lib.

Comment: I would recommend to avoid reconstructing arrays with `push`. A chain of `.map`, `.filter`, `.slice` and others is generally more ~~understandable~~ clean

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dimava for the answer. Here is the updated code

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const FirstZobj = z.object({
    items: z.array(z.object({ hello: z.literal("world") })),
});

const OtherZObj = z.object({
    items: z.array(z.object({ goodbye: z.literal("planet") })),
});

type Possibles = typeof FirstZobj | typeof OtherZObj;

const lookDeep = async<T extends Possibles>(obj: unknown, validator: T) => {
    const valid = validator.safeParse(obj);
    // alternatively: return !valid.success ? undefined : valid.data.items.slice()

    type PossibleItems = z.infer<typeof validator>["items"];
    const extractedItems: PossibleItems[number][] = [];
    if (valid.success) { for (const item of valid.data.items) { extractedItems.push(item); } }
    return extractedItems;
};

const data1 = { items: [{ hello: "world" }, { hello: "world" }] };
const data2 = { items: [{ goodbye: "planet" }] };
const data3 = { items: [{ greetings: "mars" }] };

console.log(lookDeep(data1, FirstZobj));
console.log(lookDeep(data2, OtherZObj));
console.log(lookDeep(data3, FirstZobj));
```